# MySql uncomplated Upgrade Error

Tags: apt, server, upgrade, mysql

I faced showed bellow error every apt upgrade. An mysql server frequently down. I try backup my database with mysqlpump, this backup not contain tables values. Only table construct. How can I fix this issue

```
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.29, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
Error: Unable to shut down server with process id 32298
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: Same error :`Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Checking if update is needed.
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.29, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
Error: Unable to shut down server with process id 2372
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
`